# Publishing a xform from /map to /base_link?

Tags: navigation, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all -

Trying to get up to speed on the NavStack. Presently, when I run the launch file, I get the following error:

> Waiting on transform from base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: Frame id /map does not exist!

Presently, my tf tree looks like this odom->base_link->base_laser. It makes sense that the tree *should* look like this: /map->odom->base_link->base_laser, however, I'm not sure A) who's responsibility it is to broadcast that transform and B) how to compute said transform. Any and all assistance would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9378/publishing-a-xform-from-/map-to-/base_link?/) by [jdt141](https://answers.ros.org/users/247/jdt141/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2011-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I am not wrong, that would be the responsibility of your positioning system to do that. (amcl, gmapping...).
It all depends what positioning solution you decide to use.

Have a look at the [navigation tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials), and in particular the [robotsetup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) one. It is all explained there.

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdt141](https://answers.ros.org/users/247/jdt141/) on 2011-03-10**:
Raph - Thanks very much. I had read the tutorial, and it was helpful but the gmapping documentation was more illuminating: http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping#Provided_tf_Transforms